# Predict malloc block sizes grid in C

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

I'm trying to optimize my dynamic memory usage. The thing is that I initially allocate some amount of memory for the data I get from a socket. Then, on the new data arrival I'm reallocating memory so the newly arrived part will fit into the local buffer. After some poking around I've found that malloc actually allocates a greater block than requested. In some cases significantly greater; here comes some debug info from malloc_usable_size(ptr):

> requested 284 bytes, allocated 320 bytes 
>   requested 644 bytes, reallocated 1024 bytes

It's well known that malloc/realloc are expensive operations. In most cases newly arrived data will fit into a previously allocated block (at least when I requested 644 byes and get 1024 instead), but I have no idea how I can figure that out.

The trouble is that malloc_usable_size should not be relied upon (as described in manual) and if the program requested 644 bytes and malloc allocated 1024, the excess 644 bytes may be overwritten and can not be used safely. So, using malloc for a given amount of data and then use malloc_usable_size to figure out how many bytes were really allocated isn't the way to go.

What I want is to know the block grid before calling malloc, so I will request exactly the maximum amount of bytes greater then I need, store allocated size and on the realloc check if I really need to realloc, or if the previously allocated block is fine just because it's greater.

In other words, if I were to request 644 bytes, and malloc actually gave me 1024, I want to have predicted that and requested 1024 instead.

Comment: What computer is this running on? I haven't used any computer / OS in the last twenty years where I would consider a reallocation like that an expensive operation. Have you actually measured how long it takes?

Comment: I use GCC for Linux and FreeBSD.

Comment: You're asking for something that isn't standards-required. That aside, most implementation allocators utilize an alignment/page algorithm for sizing allocations. If you want to expand a dynamic block allocated with `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc`, do what you're doing now: use `realloc()`. If the size you want to expand to already fits in the page(s) previously allocated, the cost will be marginal and the original pointer will be returned (again, this is in *practice*; not mandated by the standard ttbomk). If the requested size is too small, new allocation + copying will ensue anyway.

Comment: @gnasher729 I think he meant expensive relative to a basic operation, like an add, not in absolute time units. Heap management routines may run any time a malloc occurs, for instance block coalescing, which could cause the malloc to take quite a lot longer than usual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your particular implementation of `libc` you will have different behaviour. I have found in most cases two approaches to do the trick:

1. Use the stack, this is not always feasible, but C allows VLAs on the stack and is the most effective if you don't intend to pass your buffer to an external thread

   ```
   while (1) {
       char buffer[known_buffer_size];
       read(fd, buffer, known_buffer_size);
       // use buffer
       // released at the end of scope
   }
   ```
2. In Linux you can make excellent use of `mremap` which can enlarge/shrink memory with zero-copy guaranteed. It may move your VM mapping though. Only problem here is that it only works in chunks of system page size `sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)` which is usually `0x1000`.

   ```
   void * buffer = mmap(NULL, init_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
   while(1) {
       // if needs remapping
       {
           // zero copy, but involves a system call
           buffer = mremap(buffer, new_size, MREMAP_MAYMOVE);
       }
       // use buffer
   }
   munmap(buffer, current_size);
   ```
3. OS X has similar semantics to Linux's `mremap` through the Mach `vm_remap`, it's a little more compilcated though.

   ```
   void * buffer = mmap(NULL, init_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
   mach_port_t this_task = mach_task_self();
   while(1) {
       // if needs remapping
       {
           // zero copy, but involves a system call
           void * new_address = mmap(NULL, new_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
           vm_prot_t cur_prot, max_prot;
           munmap(new_address, current_size); // vm needs to be empty for remap
           // there is a race condition between these two calls
           vm_remap(this_task,
             &new_address,      // new address
             current_size,      // has to be page-aligned
             0,                 // auto alignment
             0,                 // remap fixed
             this_task,         // same task
             buffer,            // source address
             0,                 // MAP READ-WRITE, NOT COPY
             &cur_prot,         // unused protection struct
             &max_prot,         // unused protection struct
             VM_INHERIT_DEFAULT);
           munmap(buffer, current_size); // remove old mapping
           buffer = new_address;
       }
       // use buffer
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that the standard malloc interface does not provide the information you are looking for.  To use the information breaks the abstraction provided.

Some alternatives are:

1. Rethink your usage model.  Perhaps pre-allocate a pool of buffers at start, filling them as you go.  Unfortunately this could complicate your program more than you would like.
2. Use a different memory allocation library that does provide the needed interface.  Different libraries provide different tradeoffs in terms of fragmentation, max run time, average run time, etc.
3. Use your OS memory allocation API.  These are often written to be efficient, but will generally require a system call (unlike a user-space library).

Answer (score 0):

In my professional code, I often take advantage of the `actual size` allocated by malloc()[etc], rather than the `requested size`.  This is my function for determining the `actual` allocation size0:

```
int MM_MEM_Stat(
      void   *I__ptr_A,
      size_t *_O_allocationSize
      )
   {
   int    rCode = GAPI_SUCCESS;
   size_t size  = 0;

   /*-----------------------------------------------------------------
   ** Validate caller arg(s).
   */
#ifdef __linux__ // Not required for __APPLE__, as alloc_size() will
                 // return 0 for non-malloc'ed refs.
   if(NULL == I__ptr_A)
      {
      rCode=EINVAL;
      goto CLEANUP;
      }
#endif

   /*-----------------------------------------------------------------
   ** Calculate the size.
   */
#if defined(__APPLE__)
   size=malloc_size(I__ptr_A);
#elif defined(__linux__)
   size=malloc_usable_size(I__ptr_A);
#else
   !@#$%
#endif
   if(0 == size)
      {
      rCode=EFAULT;
      goto CLEANUP;
      }

   /*-----------------------------------------------------------------
   ** Return requested values to caller.
   */
   if(_O_allocationSize)
      *_O_allocationSize = size;

CLEANUP:

   return(rCode);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some sore research and found two interesting things about malloc realization in Linux and FreeBSD:
1) in Linux malloc increment blocks linearly in 16 byte steps, at least up to 8K, so no optimization needed at all, it's just not reasonable;
2) in FreeBSD situation is different, steps are bigger and tend to grow up with requested block size.
So, any kind of optimization is needed only for FreeBSD as Linux allocates blocks with a very tiny steps and it's very unlikely to receive less then 16 bytes of data from socket.